# SubSonic Active Record object doesn't return as IQueryable<>?

Tags: c#, activerecord, subsonic

When creating a DomainService, within .NET Ria Services and using Subsonic I can add a IQueryable method as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Server> GetServers() { return Server.All(); }
```

It compiles with no problem but when I add a method to get a specific server:

```
public IQueryable<Server> GetServer(int serverID) { return Server.SingleOrDefault( srv => srv.server_id == serverID); }
```

I get a "**cannot implicitly convert type myApp.Data.Server to System.Linq.IQueryable**.."

I've tried to append AsQueryable() to the end but that doesn't seem to work as myApp.Data.Server doesn't have that definition.

I'm at a loss of how to convert this to IQueryable, if it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're returning a single Server entity, why would you want it to be a queryable?  You've already found your entity... what queries would you execute on it?

If you really need to return a Queryable list of one item though, you can use the Find() method instead of SingleOrDefault().  SingleOrDefault's return value is simply the entity type, not an IQueryable.

Comment: ok. but i would like to use transaction scope. and i need excatly IQueryabe<>.